# .NET Login Control with jQuery dialog box not working?

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-ui, login-control, jquery-dialog

I've got a Login Control set to come up inside a jQuery dialog box. However, the login button doesn't work when in the dialog box, it works fine when I remove the dialog box. There are some field validators on the username and password that do some javascript validation, so I think there might be some conflict but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="loginBox">
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>

        <div class="accountInfo" style="float: left; width: 220px;">
            <fieldset class="login">
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Width="190"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                        CssClass="red-text" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required."
                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" >Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password" Width="190"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                        CssClass="red-text" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required."
                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br/>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" style="display: inline-block;" />
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" style="display: inline-block; font-weight: normal;">Remember Me</asp:Label>
            </fieldset>

            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 170px; padding-top: 15px;">
         <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="red-text" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Dialog
    $('#loginBox').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 420,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        title: "<h2 style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Log In</h2>",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        resizable: false,
        show: { effect: "fade", duration: 1500 }
    });
})
</script>
```

Nothing in the code behind file. I notice when I inspect the login button after the page has been rendered it has this on it:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainbody$LoginUser$LoginButton" value="Log In" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$mainbody$LoginUser$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;LoginUserValidationGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="mainbody_LoginUser_LoginButton">
```

So I am guessing that javascript isn't being run for some reason when it appears in the dialog box, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the "dialog" is placed outside/below of the "form" tag in page. Check using Firebug or other tool I'm right. If so reattach the server side controls to form via javascript.

Comment: This seems to be the problem, but how do I reattach the controls to the form via javascript??

Comment: Nevermind I got it working with: `$('#loginBox').parent().appendTo(jQuery('form:first'));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional information i found when using jQuery UI dialog box.  May be helpful.
http://www.trentjones.net/2009/03/20/jqueryui-dialog-with-aspnet-empty-post-values/